# Heroku app versioning like AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku, versioning

You know for AppEngine, I can access my old app versions by adding version name in front of my app url, e.g: `http://version1.appname.appspot.com`

How do I do that with Heroku?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your application directory and type `heroku releases`

You should see:

```
Rel   Change                          By                    When
----  ----------------------          ----------            ----------
v57   Deploy 31892bd                  youremail@gmail.com   2012-03-17 17:00:00 -0700
v56   Deploy 3dde803                  youremail@gmail.com   2012-03-17 16:49:04 -0700
v55   Deploy e93045b                  youremail@gmail.com   2012-03-17 16:43:42 -0700
```

Then, if you wish, you can do `heroku releases:rollback v57` to revert to that version.

As far as viewing them on the web, no, you cannot do v1.myapp.heroku.com, that is not possible.

Comment: You can only roll back to the last version for free. Ex. 50 back to 49 and back to 50. If you pay you can have more flexibly.

Comment: @Mab879 it is now a standard feature, I believe you can rollback more than 1. (I am not paying for it, and I had ~10 releases alone)